# Filtering an array based on a Swift enum with an associated value - w/o mentioning the associated value

Tags: swift, filter, enums

I have an enum with associated value for some of the cases:

```
enum Foo {
    case a
    case b
    case c(String?)
}
```

I also have a struct with this enum as a variable

```
struct Bar {
    var foo: Foo
}
```

I then have an array of this objects

```
let array:[Bar] = [Bar(foo: .a), Bar(foo: .c(nil)), Bar(foo: .c("someString"))]
```

I want to create a function that operates on a subset of this array, based on the cases it receives something like

```
func printOnly(objectsWithCase: Foo)
```

**So far its pretty simple, but now here's the catch: for this operation I WANT TO IGNORE the associated value.**

I would like to make this function be able to take `.c` case without mentioning an associated value, as if to say "give me the ones with `.c` regardless of the associated values".

I other words - I'd like to pass in something like `.c(_)` (this doesn't work of course) and have it return (print in this case) both `Bar(foo: .c(nil))` and `Bar(foo: .c("someString"))`

So far, I only came up with **changing the functions declaration** to take the filtering closure instead of the cases like this:

```
func printArray(array: [Bar], condition: (Bar) -> Bool) {
    let tmp = array.filter(condition)
    print(tmp)
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to do this in Swift, while passing the cases and not the condition block ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the underscore as a wild card in pattern matching operations:

```
array.filter {
    switch $0.foo {
        case .a: return true // keep a
        case .b: return false // reject b
        case .c(_): return true // keep c, regardless of assoc. value.
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the wildcard pattern,  `case .c:` would do the same.

Comment: @MartinR Nice, TIL.

Comment: I probably was not clear in the question but I'm well aware of these options. as I state in my the last line of my question - I'm interested in maintaining this function declaration: `func printOnly(objectsWithCase: Foo)`. The question is - how do you call that function? not how you implement it

Comment: @Noam You can't. `Foo.c` isn't a valid value, and the only way you can pattern match for `c` is by capturing the (pattern matching) behavior in a way that can be stored in a variable... that's what a closure is.

Answer (score 1):

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play
    enum Foo {
        case a
        case b
        case c(String?)
    }
    struct Bar {
        var foo: Foo
    }
    let array:[Bar] = [Bar(foo: .a), Bar(foo: .c(nil)), Bar(foo: .c("someString"))]
    func printArray(array: [Bar], condition: (Bar) -> Bool) {
        let tmp = array.filter(condition)
        print(tmp)
    }
    printArray(array: array) { bar in
        switch bar.foo {
        case .c:
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
```

or

```
printArray(array: array) { bar in
    if case let Foo.c = bar.foo {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

**EDIT**

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play
enum Foo: Equatable {
    case a
    case b
    case c(String?)
}
func ==(lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case (.a, .a), (.b, .b), (.c, .c):
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}
struct Bar {
    var foo: Foo
}

let array:[Bar] = [Bar(foo: .a), Bar(foo: .c(nil)), Bar(foo: .c("someString"))]
func printArray(array: [Bar], condition: (Bar) -> Bool) {
    let tmp = array.filter(condition)
    print(tmp)
}

func printOnly(objectsWithCase wantedCase: Foo) {
    printArray(array: array) { bar in
        if wantedCase == bar.foo {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
printOnly(objectsWithCase:.c(nil))
```

Comment: Yes that's a great option but its not what I'm looking for... I wish to maintaining this function declaration: `func printOnly(objectsWithCase: Foo)`. The question is - how do you call this function?

Answer (score 1):

While this is not technically what you ask for (I don't think there's any way to achieve this with enums), you can write a "fake" enum that contains a wildcard `c` that will match anything you want. This will give you the exact same syntax.

**1) Replace `Foo` with the following**

```
struct Foo: Equatable {

    let rawValue: String
    let associatedObject: String?
    let isWildcard: Bool

    fileprivate init(rawValue: String, associatedObject: String?, isWildcard: Bool) {
        self.rawValue = rawValue
        self.associatedObject = associatedObject
        self.isWildcard = isWildcard
    }

    static var a: Foo {
        return Foo(rawValue: "a", associatedObject: nil, isWildcard: false)
    }

    static var b: Foo {
        return Foo(rawValue: "b", associatedObject: nil, isWildcard: false)
    }

    static var c: Foo {
        return Foo(rawValue: "c", associatedObject: nil, isWildcard: true)
    }

    static func c(_ value: String?) -> Foo {
        return Foo(rawValue: "c", associatedObject: value, isWildcard: false)
    }
}

func ==(left: Foo, right: Foo) -> Bool {
    // Match rawValue + associatedObject unless we have a wildcard
    return (left.rawValue == right.rawValue)
      && (left.associatedObject == right.associatedObject || left.isWilcard || right.isWildcard)
}
```

**2) Implement your `printOnly` function with `==`**

```
func printOnly(objects: [Bar], with match: Foo) {
    objects.filter { $0.foo == match }.forEach { print($0) }
}
```

**3) Success**

```
printOnly(objects: array, with: .c) // [.c(nil), .c("someString")]
```

**Discussion**

The main drawback of this method, besides the additional boilerplate code, is that you are forced to create an enum value that should not be allowed. This method puts the responsibility on you to use it only as a wildcard, and not as a real enum value. It will also not guarantee you that other enum cases cannot be created, although you should be able to mitigate that by making the only initializer `fileprivate`.

Otherwise, this gives you exactly the same interface and features an enum would give you, you can define your cases just as before

```
let array = [Bar(foo: .a), Bar(foo: .c(nil)), Bar(foo: .c("Hello")]
```

Finally, you can still use it inside a switch, except you will always need to add a `default` statement.

```
switch Foo.c("Hello") {
case .a:
    print("A")
case .b:
    print("B")
case .c: // will match .c(nil) and .c("someString")
    print("C")
default:
    break
}
```